# How to remove the bottom space of the button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, web

I am working on this new website to make this result:
[image: I want to be like this]

This is my current status:
[image: Bottom space of PURCHASE button]

link of the github repo: https://github.com/rittamdebnath/papercutlabs_new

Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: Finding the part of the code with this button from your Github link is time consuming. Add all the code snippets here (css, html) that relates to the button.

Comment: tyr this section.payments .payment-card .services p.content {min-height:156px}

Comment: out use position absolute for button

Answer (score 0):

**Please add this CSS :**

```
.section.payments .payment-card {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
section.payments a.btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it may it's help you out

```
<style>
section.payments .payment-card .services p.content {
min-height: 158px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
section.payments .payment-card .services p.content{    min-height: 156px;}
```

add this     "min-height: 156px;" to above class

Answer (score 0):

To remove the space below buttons. Please use the code below:

```
section.payments .payment-card {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
section.payments a.btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do the same by simply add below css to your code:-**

section.payments .payment-card {

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 100%;
```

}

section.payments a.btn {

```
align-self: flex-end;
margin-top: auto;
```

}

** Screenshot:-**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBGr2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using absolute position for button, it will work for you in every condition on every screen, as some of the users answer above. use that position solution. You can also go with the flex solutions but you get some browser compatibility issues.